# Projection: Mollweide to Equirectangular

Tags: python, coordinate-system, maps, mathematics

I am trying to reproduce in Python a coordinate transformation of a map from Mollweide coordinates (see Figure A) to Equirectangular coordinates (see Figure B) that I saw done in Mathematica in the following post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11834/how-do-i-map-a-mollweide-projection-onto-a-sphere.

[image]

I found another post doing just the opposite (transformation from Equirectangular to Mollweide):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45108635/converting-latitude-longitude-to-x-y-mollweide-map-coordinates-using-a-newto. They do include a function for the reverse transformation that I want to do but it is not being used in their code. So I decided to do it myself.

Per definition of a coordinate transformation, the goal is to move each pixel of the grid to another location on the grid. The transformation from Mollweide to Equirectangular is implemented using the following set of parametric equations (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollweide_projection):

[image]

The definition domains of x, y, φ (latitude) and λ (longitude) are:

- x ∈ [-2*R*sqrt(2), 2*R*sqrt(2)],
- y ∈ [-R*sqrt(2), R*sqrt(2)],
- λ ∈ [-π, π],
- φ ∈ [-π/2, π/2].

As my input, I chose a JPEG picture of a Mollweide map of Earth available here: https://map-projections.net/img/jpg/mollweide.jpg.

[image]

The following code iterates through the picture and moves each pixel into another location on a new grid based on the previous equations:

```
import numpy as np
from math import sin, cos, pi, sqrt, asin
from PIL import Image

def inv_mollweide(x, y, lon_0, R):
    """Mollweide inverse tranformation"""
    
    theta = asin(y/(R*sqrt(2))) # auxiliary angle
    
    lat = asin((2*theta+sin(2*theta))/pi) # latitude
    lon = lon_0 + (pi*x)/(2*R*sqrt(2)*cos(theta)) # longitude
    
    return lat, lon

def moolweide2geodetic(data, lon_0, R):
    """Applies Mollweide inverse tranformation on each cell of the grid"""
    
    n_lat, n_lon = data.shape # retrieving number of rows and columns
    
    x = np.linspace(-2*R*sqrt(2), 2*R*sqrt(2), n_lon) # x definition domain
    y = np.linspace(-R*sqrt(2), R*sqrt(2), n_lat) # y definition domain
    
    lon = np.linspace(-pi, pi, n_lon) # longitude definition domain
    lat = np.linspace(-pi/2, pi/2, n_lat) # latitude definition domain
    
    data_proj = np.zeros((n_lat, n_lon)) # creating new array
    
    for i in range(n_lat):
        for j in range(n_lon):
            
            coord = inv_mollweide(x[j], y[i], lon_0, R) # applying Mollweide inverse tranformation on cell (i, j)
            
            i_lat = list(lat).index(min(lat, key=lambda x:abs(x-coord[0]))) # retrieving new row index
            i_lon = list(lon).index(min(lon, key=lambda x:abs(x-coord[1]))) # retrieving new colmn index
            
            data_proj[i_lat, i_lon] = data[i, j] # EDIT
    
    data_proj = np.ma.masked_invalid(data_proj) # EDIT
    
    LON, LAT = np.meshgrid(lon, lat) # EDIT
    LON1 = LON[~data_proj.mask] # EDIT
    LAT1 = LAT[~data_proj.mask] # EDIT
    data_proj_new = data_proj[~data_proj.mask] # EDIT
    
    GD = interpolate.griddata((LON1, LAT1), data_proj_new.ravel(),
                              (LON, LAT), method='linear') # EDIT
    
    GD[np.isnan(GD)] = 0 # EDIT
    
    return GD # EDIT

path = 'mollweide.jpg' # https://map-projections.net/img/jpg/mollweide.jpg

# Read image
img = Image.open(path)
width, height = img.size

newsize = (int(width/5), int(height/5)) #decreasing the quality to speed up the testing process
img = img.resize(newsize)

img_data = np.transpose(np.array(img), (2, 0, 1))
r = img_data[0, :, :]
g = img_data[1, :, :]
b = img_data[2, :, :]

lon_0, R = 0, 1

r_proj = moolweide2geodetic(r, lon_0, R) # applying Mollweide inverse tranformation on the red grid
g_proj = moolweide2geodetic(g, lon_0, R) # applying Mollweide inverse tranformation on the green grid
b_proj = moolweide2geodetic(b, lon_0, R) # applying Mollweide inverse tranformation on the blue grid

rgb_img = Image.fromarray((np.dstack((r_proj, g_proj, b_proj))).astype(np.uint8)) # recombing each color layer into an image

rgb_img.show()
rgb_img.save('equirectangular.png')
```

[image]

As you can see I am not getting an Equirectangular projection (compare with Figure B). I don't know wether it is due to my wrong understanding of the equations or my programming. Funny enough it almost looks like a sinusoidal projection (see https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/sinu.html).

**I am currently stuck, I cannot find the issue with the projection code and I am wondering if someone would have any suggestion on how to fix to this issue. Any help?**

I could add more details if needed, just tell me in the comments.

---

**EDIT 1**

As @GabrielDeLuca said, I was not actually moving the pixels in the right table (see modified code line: `data_proj[i_lat, i_lon] = data[i, j]`).

Here is the result of the transformation:

[image]

The transformation occured but some of the pixels have not been populated.

I kind of expected this issue. Should I do some kind of interpolation? If one does an interpolation then we get a better render but the quality is still rather poor around and beyond +-60 degrees in latitude:

```
data_proj = np.ma.masked_invalid(data_proj)
LON, LAT = np.meshgrid(lon, lat)
LON1 = LON[~data_proj.mask]
LAT1 = LAT[~data_proj.mask]
data_proj_new = data_proj[~data_proj.mask]

GD = interpolate.griddata((LON1, LAT1), data_proj_new.ravel(),
                          (LON, LAT), method='linear')

GD[np.isnan(GD)] = 0
```

[image]

If we compare this tranformation to the one coming from Mathematica then one can see that it is of much better quality:

[image]

**So I assume there is something missing or that could be improve. Is there a better way to produce the projected array?**

---

**EDIT 2**

I figured out why the top/bottom/corners were messed up. It was not due to the algorithm but to the input.

The difference between the two maps (Mathematica post vs. this post), is that my map was not cropped properly at the top/bottom/left/right of the image.

[image]

In fact if I crop the image properly, then I get the following result:

[image]

[image]

**The next and final step I would say would be to find a better solution to the unpopulated pixels. The interpolation is in my opinion not a perfect solution. The solution proposed by @J.Monticolo might be a good alternative. Any thougths?**

Comment: Hi, it looks like projecting to Mollweide again.

Comment: If you really want to move pixels, see what happens with `data_proj[i_lat, i_lon] = data[i, j]` instead.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca I computed new latitude and longitude indexes and didn't even put them into the new table, thanks. So the transformation occured but there's still an issue from what I can see. It may be that I should pick a smaller size array, do some kind of interpolation or just change my indexes derivation. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Hi @loïc-poncin, this is a good question. I don't know how the programs for reprojection work. You make some nearest neighbour election in fact, retrieving the index of the minimum difference. Surely your program will work on filling the original table (iterating over the projected image, filling each latlon pixel with the closest xy pixel value returned by the projection function), but with the direct projection function instead of the inverse. It would be very helpful to see the answer of someone more familiar with this kind of raster manipulation from the source code.

Comment: To speed-up the process, I think you can compute the transformation just once for all the bands, as a pixel RGB has the same location in the end.

Comment: re: the bold question, if you don't wish to write the interpolation yourself opencv has a function which can handle this, [`remap()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gab75ef31ce5cdfb5c44b6da5f3b908ea4)

Comment: @J.Monticolo Good idea, I will implement that at a later date and add it to this post.

Comment: @mikecatt The question was not so much about whether or not I knew how to do the interpolation, but rather if I should do it or use another method. I edited my question, and as you can see before and after interpolation the corners and top/bottom sections of the image have a poor quality whereas the transformation in Mathematica is better (and both are supposed to produce the same transformation). Here this is just a picture, but what happens if I choose to apply this tranformation on data such as population density? I need the transformation as complete and accurate as I can.

Comment: @LoïcPoncin: just had an idea but I've difficulties to implement it. Instead of iterate over each Mollweide image pixels and transform it into equirectangular, I'm interested of the result of create a blank equirectangular image, iterate over each pixel, transform the pixel with equirectangular to Mollweide, and with the result, pick the corresponding pixel in the original image.

Comment: @J.Monticolo It is a great idea. It would provide a better result than for the interpolation I think. I edited my post because I also noticed something wrong with the input. I will try to find some time to work on that solution of yours.